# equivalence of normed spaces and separability

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, separable-spaces

The question can be trivial, but I can not figure it out myself.

Assume we have that $X$ is a normed space, with norm $\| {\cdot}\|_{1}$ and topology generated by the norm. Let us consider another norm, let's say $\|{\cdot}\|_{2}$, which is equivalent to $\|{\cdot}\|_{1}$.

Then, if the space $(X, \| {\cdot}\|_{1})$ is separable, does it follows that the space $(X, \| {\cdot}\|_{2})$ is also separable?

Comment: Separability (or non-separabilty) is a property of the topology $T$ itself : $T$ is separable iff there exists a countable $D$ such that $D\cap t\ne \phi$ whenever $\phi \ne t \in T$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because $\operatorname{id}\colon(X,\|\cdot\|_1)\longrightarrow(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ is a homeomorphism, and therefore the image of a dense subset is also a dense subset.